# Backbone: rendering dynamic content in jst.ejs files

Tags: backbone.js, ejs

I'm following along with Ryan Bates backbone.js tutorial for Rails. He uses jst.eco templating. However, I'm using jst.ejs files.

His view creates some content that he wants to insert into the template, namely "Entries go here"

```
$(this.el).html(this.template(entries: "Entries go here"));
 return this;
```

and it will be inserted in  `<%= @entries %>` in the template

```
<h1>App Name</h1>

<%= @entries %>
```

I'm doing this with index.jst.ejs files and it's not working.

First. Does anyone know what tags I should be using in the template to render dynamic content?

Second, is it still correct to do `entries: "Entries go here"` inside of the template() parentheses, as in

```
$(this.el).html(this.template({entries: "Entries go here"}));
```

Note, I'm not using coffeescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't need a @ or 'this' in front of 'entries' in the template.

Views/entries/index

```
 render: function(){

    $(this.el).html(this.template({

        entries: "Entries go here"

    }));
    return this;
  }
```

Templates/entries/index.jst.ejs

```
<%= entries %>
```