# Reuse EJS template to render ERB in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, templates, sprockets, ejs

I have a web app that renders views client-side with EJS. EJS uses the ERB syntax:

```html
<!-- /views/posts/_comment.jst.ejs -->

<article id=<%= comment.id %>>
<%= comment.body %>
</article>
```

I’m also rendering the view with the Rails server. The partial to render it server-side would look identical to the EJS. How can I reuse the EJS and have Rails think it’s a standard ERB partial?

```html
<!-- /views/posts/comments.html.erb -->

<h2>Comments:</h2>

<!— This doesn’t work: —>
<%= render partial: ‘_comment.jst.ejs’, :formats => [:erb] %>
```

Comment: <%= render partial: ‘comment.jst.ejs’ %> not sure about extensions

Comment: The extensions are messy, but they’re necessary so Sprockets compiles the EJS for the client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just take help from this links

[how to use includes/partials in Rails 3 Backbone ejs.jst files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389917/how-to-use-includes-partials-in-rails-3-backbone-ejs-jst-files)

[Backbone: rendering dynamic content in jst.ejs files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399306/backbone-rendering-dynamic-content-in-jst-ejs-files)

Comment: That doesn’t work. It says: `Missing partial posts/comment, application/comment with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :mustache]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/Matt/Sites/my-app/app/views”`

Comment: send me your file name which you want to render and also tell me which type of content you want to show such as javascript, html etc

Comment: I want the filename to be “_comment.jst.ejs” and I want it to render as HTML/ERB (i.e. parsed by Rails).

Comment: The filename needs to contain “jst.ejs” so Sprockets knows to compile the template for client-side rendering.